# ASP.NET Setting SelectedValue that doesn't belong to the list does not trigger Exception

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, webforms, drop-down-menu

I have an ASP.Net form where I use a DropDownList control to display data retrieved from a table. However setting the SelectedValue of the DropDownList to a value not existing in the dropdown list does not trigger an exception.

```
Try
    dropDownList.SelectedValue = value
Catch ex as Exception
    Throw
End Try
```

In the code above, if I assign a value that does not belong to the list's item, it does not throw an Exception. It just selects the first item in the list when the HTML is rendered.

Any ideas why?

By the way, I have a blank (String.Empty) item as the first item in the list. I also used DataBind() to bind the listItem to a DataTable. Does that make any difference?

Comment: I assume it's by design. Is there a particular reason you want it to throw an exception?

Comment: I have to notify the user that the data loaded from the database does not belong to the available answers (and that he/she needs to change it). I don't maintain the database for the user's answers, but I do maintain the list of choices for the dropdown

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Thanks guys for answering. What I ultimately did was used the FindByValue() method of the Dropdownlist and see if the value exists in the list:

```
If Not DropDownlist.Items.FindByValue(value) Is Nothing Then
    ' do what the Exception is supposed to do '
Else
    DropDownList.SelectedValue = value
End If
```

The FindByValue() returns Nothing if the passed parameter does not belong to the list. I avoided using an Exception (which is heavy on processing) as a way to trap the problem, and it works exactly as I needed.

Comment: I realize this is 9 years too late, but just wanted to point out that you have the logic backwards because of the double negative, there shouldn't be a `not` at the beginning.

Answer (score 4):

> When the selected value is not in the
>   list of available values ***and a
>   postback is performed***, an
>   ArgumentOutOfRangeException  is
>   thrown:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listcontrol.selectedvalue.aspx

Comment: Thanks. But I need to check if the data I got from the database belongs to the list on initial page load.

Comment: Sorry, I was responding to why it doesn't throw an exception. For your solution you're going to have to check the dropdownlists's Items propery, maybe using the Contains method. Me.ComboBox1.Items.Contains()

Comment: I rewrote my code to check whether the item exists in the Items property. What about Me.Dropdown.Items.FindByValue()? Do you recommend it?

Comment: Yep, totally use that. I was looking at a WinForms ComboBox which I assumed had the same methods on the collection and Contains() was the best one that it had. FindByValue() is much better.

Answer (score 0):

you can use this method for easy to set SelectedValue

```
    private void DropDownSelectSafeValue(this DropDownList Drp, string Value) {             
        if (Drp.Items.FindByValue(Value) == null)
            Drp.SelectedValue = Value;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I think the NOT should be removed. Otherwise, it's the reverse. This is what I did.

```
If ddAssignedDTL.Items.FindByValue(sqlreader("C_AssignedDTL").ToString) Is Nothing Then

 ' do what the Exception is supposed to do '
 ddAssignedDTL.Items.Add(New ListItem("<Invalid DTL-" & sqlreader("C_AssignedDTL").ToString & ">", sqlreader("C_AssignedDTL").ToString))
 ddAssignedDTL.SelectedValue = sqlreader("C_AssignedDTL").ToString
 DTL = sqlreader("C_AssignedDTL").ToString
 ddAssignedDTL.BackColor = Drawing.Color.Red
Else
 ddAssignedDTL.SelectedValue = sqlreader("C_AssignedDTL").ToString
 DTL = sqlreader("C_AssignedDTL").ToString()
End If
```